# Why does this VBA script create a runtime error 5?

Tags: excel, vba

I've built a VBA macro for creating few pivot tables based on data which is always similar. The macro works as intended on my own older laptop, which may not be running the latest build of Excel, but not on my colleagues Win11 laptop. The macro is built for a specific input, and I am not looking to make it more dynamic. It just has to work as intended.

The VBA code of the problematic macro is:

```
Sub Macro_Varasto_varannot()
'
' Macro_Varasto_varannot Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:= _
        "=Kaupinta Omistus", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Omistus"
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=">0", Operator:=xlFilterValues
    
    Range("A1:M46").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets.Add
***
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Sheet2!R1C1:R161C13", Version:=8).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
        "Sheet3!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable2", DefaultVersion:=8
***
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Myyntialue"), "Count of Myyntialue", xlCount
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Projektinimi"), "Count of Projektinimi", xlCount
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Tuotenimi"), "Count of Tuotenimi", xlCount
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Myyntialue" _
        )
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Projektinimi" _
        )
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Tuotenimi" _
        )
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 3
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Määrä tn"), "Sum of Määrä tn", xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Arvo eur"), "Sum of Arvo eur", xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").CompactLayoutRowHeader = _
        "Myyntialue/projekti/tuotenimi"
    Range("B3").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").DataPivotField.PivotItems( _
        "Sum of Määrä tn").Caption = "Summa / Määrä tn"
    Range("C3").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").DataPivotField.PivotItems( _
        "Sum of Arvo eur").Caption = "Summa / Arvo eur"
    Range("G7").Select
    Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = 20.83
    Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 22.17
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("N29").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=11
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=8
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:= _
        "=Omistus", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=Varanto"
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:= _
        "Varanto"
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=">0", Operator _
        :=xlFilterValues
    Range("A1:M69").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Sheet4!R1C1:R99C13", Version:=8).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:= _
        "Sheet5!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable3", DefaultVersion:=8
    Sheets("Sheet5").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable3").PivotFields("Myyntialue"), "Count of Myyntialue", xlCount
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable3").PivotFields("Projektinimi"), "Count of Projektinimi", xlCount
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable3").PivotFields("Tuotenimi"), "Count of Tuotenimi", xlCount
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Myyntialue")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Projektinimi" _
        )
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 2
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").PivotFields("Tuotenimi")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 3
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable3").PivotFields("Määrä tn"), "Sum of Määrä tn", xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable3").PivotFields("Arvo eur"), "Sum of Arvo eur", xlSum
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").CompactLayoutRowHeader = _
        "Myyntialue/projekti/tuotenimi"
    Range("B3").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").DataPivotField.PivotItems( _
        "Sum of Määrä tn").Caption = "Summa / Määrä tn"
    Range("C3").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3").DataPivotField.PivotItems( _
        "Sum of Arvo eur").Caption = "Summa / Arvo eur"
    Range("F5").Select
    Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = 18.67
    Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 18
End Sub
```

The part of the code that causes the error is highlighted between ***'s.
I would appreciate any support very much.

Comment: I'd suggest you remove the `Version:=` and `DefaultVersion:=` arguments.

Comment: I thought of this – will try and report whether this works or not. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sharing [.xlsm](https://docs.fileformat.com/spreadsheet/xlsm/) files with users/colleagues that don't use the same Excel platform may sometimes (or very often) cause a [VBA runtime error 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/invalid-procedure-call-or-argument-error-5) since the code in which the macro is written can we slightly different from one platform to another.

But in your case, I think it's much more due to the way the code was written and/or recorded.

One of the parameters that made the [PivotTable.PivotCache](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/office/vba/api/excel.pivotcache.createpivottable) method, is *TableDestination*. In your code, you're telling Excel (in line 17), every time the code is run, to create a new sheet that has an auto-incremented name (Sheet3). So if this sheet happen to be deleted (for some reason) after the first run of the macro, and then you re-run your macro, the error 5 will occur.

###### Try this :

1. In line 17, replace `Sheets.Add` by this `Sheets.Add.Name = "PivoTable_Sheet"`
2. In line 21, replace `"Sheet3!R3C1"` by this `"PivoTable_Sheet!R3C1"`
3. In line 23, replace `Sheets("Sheet3").Select` by this    `Sheets("PivoTable_Sheet").Select`

Comment: Thanks for the input. This will not be a problem since the data is always located in the first sheet. Could the version specifications in the code be responsible of the error? It seems that the default version is currently 12, but the version in the code is 8.

Comment: At first, try to change `DefaultVersion:=8` to `DefaultVersion:=12`. You can even remove `DefaultVersion:=8` as @Rory suggested in the comments. If any of these won't resolve your colleagues problem, try the workaround I explained in my answer.